# Understanding the proof of Fenchel-Rockafellar Theorem In Brezis

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, duality-theorems

I'm reading the proof of Fenchel-Rockafellar's theorem in ''Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations'' by Haim Brezis.

> Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $\varphi, \psi: E \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ convex functions. Assume there exists $x_{0} \in E$ such that $\varphi(x_0) < +\infty, \psi(x_0) < +\infty$, and $\varphi$ is continuous at $x_{0}$. Then
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \inf _{x \in E}\{\varphi(x)+\psi(x)\} &=\sup _{f \in E^{\star}}\left\{-\varphi^{\star}(-f)-\psi^{\star}(f)\right\} \\
> &=\max _{f \in E^{\star}}\left\{-\varphi^{\star}(-f)-\psi^{\star}(f)\right\}.
> \end{aligned}
> $$

In the proof, I read page 16

> From (16) and (17) we obtain
> $$
> \varphi^{\star}(-\frac{f}{k})\leq -\frac{\alpha}{k}
> $$
> $$
> \psi^{\star}(\frac{f}{k}) \leq \frac{\alpha}{k} - a
> $$

I don't  understand how do we get there.

For instance the first inequality since $\forall (x, \lambda) \in epi \varphi$
$$
<\frac{f}{k},x> + \lambda \geq \frac{\alpha}{k}  
$$
And
$$
\varphi(x) \leq \lambda
$$
We have
$$
<-\frac{f}{k},x> - \lambda +\varphi(x) -\varphi(x) \leq -\frac{\alpha}{k}  
$$
Then
$$
\varphi^{\star}(-\frac{f}{k}) - \lambda +\varphi(x)  \leq -\frac{\alpha}{k}  
$$
But I don't see how I can conclude

Is anyone able to help please ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all notice that (for any $\varphi:E\to(-\infty,+\infty]$):
\begin{equation*}
    \varphi^{*}(f)=\sup_{x\in E}\{\langle f,x\rangle-\varphi(x)\}=\sup_{x\in D(\varphi)}\{\langle f,x\rangle-\varphi(x)\},\ \text{for all}\ f\in E^{*}.
\end{equation*}
(because if $\bar{x}\not\in D(\varphi)$, then, $\langle f,\bar{x}\rangle-\varphi(\bar{x})=-\infty$ and if $D(\varphi)=\varnothing$, then, $\sup_{x\in D(\varphi)}\{\langle f,x\rangle-\varphi(x)\}=-\infty,\ \text{for all}\ f\in E^{*}$ by definition of supremum). Now, from the proof we have the following:
\begin{align*}
    \langle f,x\rangle+k\lambda&\geq\alpha,\ \forall(x,\lambda)\in C, \\
    \langle f,x\rangle+k\lambda&\leq\alpha,\ \forall(x,\lambda)\in B.
\end{align*}
Where $k>0$, $C=epi(\varphi)=\{(x,\lambda)\in E\times\mathbb{R}\ |\ \varphi(x)\leq\lambda\}$ and $B=\{(x,\lambda)\in E\times\mathbb{R}\ |\ \lambda\leq a-\psi(x)\}$ ($a\in\mathbb{R}$). Also from the proof we know that $D(\varphi),D(\psi)\not=\varnothing$, thus, for every $x\in D(\varphi)$ we have that $(x,\varphi(x))\in C$ (because $\varphi(x)\leq\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(x)\in\mathbb{R}$) and for every $x\in D(\psi)$ we have that $(x,a-\psi(x))\in B$ (because $a-\psi(x)\leq a-\psi(x)$ and $a-\psi(x)\in\mathbb{R}$). In consequence:
\begin{align*}
    \langle f,x\rangle+k\varphi(x)&\geq\alpha,\ \forall x\in D(\varphi), \\
    \langle f,x\rangle+k(a-\psi(x))&\leq\alpha,\ \forall x\in D(\psi).
\end{align*}
Therefore (just by manipulating those inequalities):
\begin{align*}
    \langle-\frac{f}{k},x\rangle-\varphi(x)&\leq-\frac{\alpha}{k},\ \forall x\in D(\varphi), \\
    \langle \frac{f}{k},x\rangle-\psi(x)&\leq\frac{\alpha}{k}-a,\ \forall x\in D(\psi).
\end{align*}
Hence, by taking the supremum over $D(\varphi)$ and respectively over $D(\psi)$ we get:
\begin{align*}
    \varphi^{*}\left(-\frac{f}{k}\right)&\leq-\frac{\alpha}{k}, \\
    \psi^{*}\left(\frac{f}{k}\right)&\leq\frac{\alpha}{k}-a.
\end{align*}
Which is the desired result.